# How to retrieve custom fields of contacts from Public Folder using Exchange 2010 EWS 2.0

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Can anyone suggest me how to connect to Exchange Server 2010(Client Access, Hub) and retrieve contacts from the Public folder. I have Exchange Server 2010 and **I need to connect to Exchange Server via my asp.net/C# application and I am using EWS Managed API 2.0 to connect and retrieve contacts from Exchange 2010 public folder database.**

**Challenges are :**
**How can we retrieve custom contact fields using EWS API ?** Is there any way to achieve and retrieve custom fields that are already set inside the contacts of Exchange 2010 Public Folder Database.

It would be a great help if anyone could suggest me how to retrieve contacts & their custom fields which are not visible in OWA contact form of the Public folder in Exchange Server 2010.

Is there any workaround to achieve this functionality or any alternative way. Please suggest me?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
string ExchangeContactFolder = Configuration.ExchangeContactFolder;
Folder ContactFolder = GetTopLevelFolder(_service, ExchangeContactFolder);
ItemView itemView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
FindItemsResults<Item> searchResults = _service.FindItems(ContactFolder.Id, itemView);
int totalContacts = searchResults.TotalCount;
 
//Setting properties for Custom Fields.
Guid FacebookGuid = new Guid("{a49b36f1-7895-4637-98ec-1ca35a345095}");
var FacebookAddress = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(FacebookGuid, "Facebook", MapiPropertyType.String);
 
itemView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
itemView.PropertySet.Add(FacebookAddress);
 
FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = _service.FindItems(ContactFolder.Id, view);
                foreach (Item item in contactItems)
                {
                    if (item is Contact)
                    {
                        string strFacebookAddress = string.Empty;
               contact.GetLoadedPropertyDefinitions();
               //item.TryGetProperty(FacebookAddress, out strFacebookAddress);
               contact.TryGetProperty(FacebookAddress, out strFacebookAddress);
               strContacts.Add(bcSearch);
                    }
                }
            }
            return strContacts;
```

Comment: So you talk about public folders but your code just accesses the Local Contacts folder? does that work ? Are you asking how to access a particular public folder ? May try to ask your question step by step in this case

Comment: Hi @GlenScales, I am able to retrieve contacts from Public Folder as mentioned in configuration file, but I am retrieving only default exchange 2010 contacts fields. I am not able to retrieve contact's custom fields. So how can I retrieve custom fields from contact ?

Comment: That code you posted won't return the properties in the foreach loop because you don't request them eg you have defined and ItemView called itemView but you don't use that in the second FindItems method call (your using a variable called view). Also don't use int.Max Value you should set it to 1000 and page the results. My first suggestion is clean up the example you posted so you have one search and one propertyset to use.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set your GUID it will never work

change it to

```
var FacebookAddress = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "Facebook", MapiPropertyType.String);
```